Poisson model with left-censored data
I observe a setting where every individual may contract on a monthly annuity that pays out after event A realises and is contingent on survival. Therefore, some individuals might never receive annuities although they contracted on them because they die before event A occurs. My hypothesis is that those who life longer after event A occurs are more likely to contract on annuities. To be clear, the outcome is months lived after A. I would like to study this using a Poisson model. However, the problem is that event A is individual specific and for a fractions of my data A did not realise yet. Hence, I potentially have quite some wrong zeros because a zero can either mean that an individual died before A occured or that A did not occur yet but the individual still lives.
Would be glad about any ideas on how to overcome this issue!

You question is a little ambiguous, but I assume by "Poisson model" you mean a generalised linear model with Poisson errors. If so, this isn't really the appropriate kind of analysis for these data. In fact, this is a problem that survival analysis was built to deal with.
Here is a link to a paper that outlines how to go about fitting these kinds of models:
Clark TG, Bradburn MJ, Love SB, Altman DG. Survival analysis part I: basic concepts and first analyses. Br J Cancer. 2003 Jul 21;89(2):232-8. doi: 10.1038/sj.bjc.6601118. PMID: 12865907; PMCID: PMC2394262.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2394262/
There are lots of tutorials for these kinds of analyses too, depending on your data structure and question. There is also quite a bit of literature on how to deal with "erroneous" zeros, but how best to deal with them depends on how much information you have about what the zero actually indicates.
